# Bash: Export Environment Variable from Script file and Discoverable by Node process.env

Tags: node.js, bash, environment-variables

**Goal: Set Environment variable from Bash script file and discoverable via Node [process.env](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_env)**

**Following effort works from macOS console, as would be expected:**

I have created the following typescript file `process.env.ts` that outputs to console environment variable `TEST_ENV_VALUE`:

```js
declare let process: {
    env: {
        TEST_ENV_VALUE: string;
    };
};

console.log('process.env.TEST_ENV_VALUE', process.env.TEST_ENV_VALUE);
```

**package.json** script contains:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test:process": "ts-node test/process.env.ts"
  },
```

When I perform the following directly within macOS console, environment variable `TEST_ENV_VALUE` is discoverable by `process.env.ts`:

```sh
$ unset TEST_ENV_VALUE
$ export TEST_ENV_VALUE="FOO"
$ echo $TEST_ENV_VALUE
FOO
$ npm run test:process
> ts-node test/process.env.ts

process.env.TEST_ENV_VALUE FOO
```

Success shows that `process.env.TEST_ENV_VALUE` returns value of **FOO**.

**Attempt creating Bash Script File with same console script**

The following bash script file **set_env_variable.sh** is attempting to replicate what was able to be performed within macOS console:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

USAGE="\nUsage: $0\n
[-h|--help]\n
--value\n
"

usage() { echo -e ${USAGE} 1>&2; exit 1; }

# read the options
OPTS=`getopt -o h --long help,value: -n 'set_env_variable.sh' -- "$@"`
if [ $? != 0 ] ; then echo "Failed parsing options." >&2 ; usage ; exit 1 ; fi
eval set -- "$OPTS"

HELP=false
TEST_ENV_VALUE="TEST"

while true; do
  case "$1" in
    -h | --help )       usage ;;
    --value )           TEST_ENV_VALUE="$2" ; shift; shift ;;
    -- )                shift; break ;;
    * )                 break ;;
  esac
done

echo -e '\n-------------------------\n'
echo TEST_ENV_VALUE="${TEST_ENV_VALUE}"
echo -e '\n-------------------------\n'
unset TEST_ENV_VALUE
export TEST_ENV_VALUE="${TEST_ENV_VALUE}"

npm run test:process
```

However, when **set_env_variable.sh** executed, environment variable `TEST_ENV_VALUE` is not discoverable by `process.env.ts`:

```sh
$ unset TEST_ENV_VALUE
$ ./set_env_variable.sh --value "BAR"
-------------------------
TEST_ENV_VALUE=BAR
-------------------------
> act-qa@1.3.0 test:process /Users/jeffrey.tanner/github/ACT/act-qa
> ts-node test/process.env.ts

process.env.TEST_ENV_VALUE
```

In other words, `process.env.TEST_ENV_VALUE` returns undefined.

Assistance appreciated in creating a bash script that will export an environment variable that is discoverable by node process.env. Thank you

Comment: What happens when you run the script as #!/bin/bash as opposed to /usr/bin/env?

Comment: @RamanSailopal Thank you for your reply. Good idea. Same results. `process.env.TEST_ENV_VALUE` returns undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you unsetting the variable then exporting it again?

```
unset TEST_ENV_VALUE
export TEST_ENV_VALUE="${TEST_ENV_VALUE}"
```

That, by definition, is exporting an empty string. Remove those two lines and replace

```
TEST_ENV_VALUE="TEST"
```

with

```
export TEST_ENV_VALUE="TEST"
```

Answer (score 0):

@KurisRader

I reworked based on your suggestion:

```
HELP=false
VALUE=""

while true; do
  case "$1" in
    -h | --help )       usage ;;
    --value )           VALUE="$2" ; shift; shift ;;
    -- )                shift; break ;;
    * )                 break ;;
  esac
done

echo -e '\n-------------------------\n'
echo TEST_ENV_VALUE="${VALUE}"
echo -e '\n-------------------------\n'

unset TEST_ENV_VALUE
export TEST_ENV_VALUE="${VALUE}"
```